# How do you efficiently do a full text search in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, search

From my experience, the search provided by Gmail or GMX is far superior to the builtin search of Thunderbird. It is faster, especially when including the email body, and more precise. In Thunderbird I really have a hard time to find an email that is a few months old and for which I do not remember the sender.

Are there any workflows or addons to improve Thunderbird's full text search?

Using an external tool would be OK for me, too.

Comment: If you go to Thunderbird's add-on extension manager and search for 'search improve' you'll get a list of add-ons that may help. The Expression Search /GMAIL UI 0.8.6 appears to be popular. This may be one of those things that are hit or miss depending on what you like.

Comment: For an external solution you might want to give [Mailstore Home](http://www.mailstore.com/en/mailstore-home.aspx) a try. It has a `Extremely Fast Search` feature.